# How do you increase spell use in dark souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

When playing a caster character in Dark Souls 2 most of the spells have a very limited use amount. Is there a way to increase these besides using restorative items like rouge water?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leveling up the [**Attunement**](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/attunement) stat will give you extra spell uses. There is also a ring that grants additional spell uses, it's called [**Northen Ritual Band**](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/northern-ritual-band)

I hope this helps

Comment: There are other items that increase spell use, such as Hexer's Hood. Also, there are items such as Amber Herbs that restore uses.

Answer (score 7):

You can also slot spells in multiple attunement slots (given you have the slots). For example, lets say you have 2 attunement slots, and you have two "soul arrow" you can slot them both (1 in one slot, the other in the other slot) and get two times the uses.